# If two different gauge transformations of an action commute, does it imply anything?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, variational-calculus

If two different gauge transformations of a Lagrangian commute with each other, does it imply anything?

Comment: What is the context for your question?

Comment: That the gauge group is abelian.

Comment: @Prahar If there's an action with a specific number of gauge transformations and if some of those transformations commute with each other but the commutators of the other transformations are linear combinations of some or all of those transformations, then we know that the gauge group is closed. Is there any special implication of the fact that the commutators of some of the gauge transformations vanish? It's possible it doesn't imply anything. I was just curious.

Comment: You understand the generators in the Cartan subalgebra of the gauge group commute among themselves? So you stumbled on two such. What implications do you expect?